# Sampling the Sine Function

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing

> Consider the sampled sine function, $f(n)=\sin(\omega n)$, where $n$ is an integer.
>
> If $\omega_2 = 3\pi/2$, does there exist an $0 \leq \omega_1 \leq \pi$ such that $\sin(\omega_1 n)=\sin(\omega_2 n)$ for all $n$?

Note the answer is yes for the cosine function - that is, $\cos(3\pi/2n)=\cos(\pi/2n)$ identically.

I think for sine, there does not exist $\omega_1$, but have not been able to prove it or find a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not. If it were possible, taking $n=1$ we have $\sin(w_1)=\sin(\frac{3 \pi}{2})$ for some $w_1\in[0,\pi]$. But $\sin(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in[0,\pi]$, and $\sin(\frac{3 \pi}{2})=-1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sinbadh. This is rather interesting, because my college instructor has always said there is no difference between sine and cosine except a mere phase difference. As your answer shows, there is major difference between them.

Comment: @J.Sanders Is there? Could you not get the same thing for $\cos$ if you shifted the allowable range for $\omega_1$?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I don't see how you can do that. It seems that:
If $\omega_2 = 3\pi/2$, there always exist a $\omega_1$ such that: $s \leq \omega_1 \leq t$, $t-s=\pi$, and $\cos(\omega_1 n)=\cos(\omega_2 n)$ for all $n$.

Comment: @J.Sanders You need to shift $\omega_2$ too. However, my point was that your instructor is right. There is no difference between the two except for a phase shift.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I thought about this a bit more. It turns out that the set of all $\cos(\omega_1 n)$ for $\omega_1\in[0,\pi)$ contains all functions of the form $\cos(\omega n)$ for any $\omega$. However, for $\sin(\omega_2 n)$, we need $\omega_2\in[0,2\pi)$ (double the range) to include all the possible functions. This seems like a significant difference - how can this be understood in the context of a phase shift?

Comment: @J.Sanders Simply because $\sin(\theta) = \cos(\theta-\pi/2)$. Also, wouldn't $\sin$ need only $\omega_2 \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 About the range of $\sin$: I am having trouble finding $\omega_2$ for $\sin(3\pi/4)$.

Comment: @J.Sanders $\sin(3\pi/4) = \sin(\pi/4)$.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I made a typo. I meant to say I could not find $\omega_2 \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ for $\sin(3\pi/4n)$. In particular, $\sin(\pi/4n) \neq \sin(3\pi/4n)$.

Comment: @J.Sanders $3\pi/4$ I don't know about, but back to your original question, $\sin(3\pi/2 \cdot n) = \sin(-\pi/2 \cdot n)$.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Yes, I agree with you on the $\sin(3\pi/2 \cdot n)$ equality. I spent more time looking for an $\omega \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ for $\sin(3\pi/4 \cdot n)$ but am unsuccessful thus far.

Comment: @J.Sanders You won't find one in that range. The requirement is that the two frequencies sum to $2\pi$.